# How make cutting in div from rectangle?

Tags: html, css

I want cutting from div the rectangle with css.

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWHj9.png

I want cutting area upping transparent,  which pick up body background color. (transparent)

How to make it?

Comment: Would have helped if you provided HTML for what you already have tried.

Comment: box-shadow/mix-blend-mode/mask/clip-path are avalaible options nowdays, which one have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea could be done with borders with opacity set.

```css
.bg {
width:400px;
height: 300px;
background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/400/300')
}

.weirdBox {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 30px 50px;
   border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
<div class="weirdBox"></div>
</div>
```